# Transmission BT stops downloading, "Error: Protocol error"

Tags: bittorrent, transmission

I'm running headless transmission-daemon 2.84 on utopic 14.10.

I tested a couple of torrents after first install and they completed downloading. However after 24 hours, I now have an error with any torrents that transmission tries to download.

I do not have permission to post screenshots so I can only describe the error.

On the webui, the torrent has stopped downloading, and the completion percentage bar has this message:

```
Error: Protocol error (/path/to/file/filename.mp4)
```

*How should I proceed?*

Comment: did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Check the permissions on the save directory. Make sure transmission can write there.

Comment: Please elaborate your answer a bit. (How to check the permissions, how should they be, how can one fix them, etc.) Thank you!